# JS Logical operators - OR, AND ('||', '&&') in switch statement

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, logical-operators

The below function is working as expected except case noticed in a comment, namely, for each number:

- if the number is divisible by three I want to log out the word `fizz` instead of that number
- if the number is divisible by five I want to log out the word `buzz` instead of that number.
- And if a number is divisible by both 3 and 5 I want to log out the word `fizzbuzz` instead of that number.

Example - 1

```js
const FizzBuzz = (num) => {
 for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
  const foo = 0;
  switch (foo) {
   case (i % 3 || i % 5): console.log('fizzbuzz');
   // expect in this case should be work with logical operator '&&': (i % 3 && i % 5)
    break;
   case i % 3: console.log('fizz');
    break;
   case i % 5: console.log('buzz');
    break;
   default: console.log(i);
  }
 }
}

FizzBuzz(20)
```

This is how I know - With switch-case statement preferable use:

Example 2

```js
switch(true) {
    case (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0): console.log('fizzbuzz');
    break;
    // etc...
}
```

But with the instance of code above (Example 1: where `switch(foo)` doesn't have the constant value like `true`), it looks more flexible and readable.
And in "Example 1", as I understood, the operator `||` works like operator `&&` and vice versa.

The "Example 1" works perfectly as result. But I can't understand Why. Primarily my question is - Why the logical operator `OR` behave as an operator `AND` in this example??

Thnx in advance.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QPZ0pIK_wsc

Comment: You have a correct case in Example 2, but you do not make a comparison in Example 1. `(i % 3 || i % 5)` you need to use `===`

Comment: No, for this exercise you definitely should not use `switch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're switching on `foo`, and `foo` is 0, so `case <expression>` will run when `<expression>` evaluates to `0`.

So, `case i % 3` runs when expected, because you want the `i % 3` case to run when that evaluates to 0. Same for `i % 5`. But

```
case (i % 3 || i % 5)
```

, when `i` is a multiple of 15, resolves to

```
case (15 % 3 || 15 % 5)
```

->

```
case (0 || 0)
```

Because `0` is falsey, the `||` will mean that *both* `15 % 3` and `15 % 5` must be `0` for the `case` there to resolve to `0` (and thus match `foo`'s `0`).

If you used `&&`, then the `&&` expression will evaluate to the *first falsey value*, rather than requiring *both* `%`s to resolve to `0`, eg when `i` is 3:

```
case (3 % 3 && 3 % 5)
```

->

```
case (0 && 2)
```

->

```
case 0
```

which then matches `foo`'s `0`, despite the fact that only one of the conditions in the `&&` resolved to 0.

It's extremely unintuitive. Don't use `switch` here. If you had to use `switch`, I'd highly recommend setting `foo` to `true` instead, and using `=== 0` tests:

```js
const FizzBuzz = (num) => {
  for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    const foo = true;
    switch (foo) {
      case i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0:
        console.log('fizzbuzz');
        break;
      case i % 3 === 0:
        console.log('fizz');
        break;
      case i % 5 === 0:
        console.log('buzz');
        break;
      default:
        console.log(i);
    }
  }
}

FizzBuzz(20)
```

Comment: Yes, exactly! I've been overlooking that the `0` is equal to `false` and now I've learned that the switch statement has a strict comparison in the matching of the case's values with header expression. Thnx! Hope this question will be useful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

The code in Example 1 works because you switch on the variable foo which is set to 0.
The code in the first case is evaluated to 0:

```
15 % 3 || 15 % 5 = 0
```

This value gets compared to foo which is 0 and so the JS code enters the first case.

In JavaScript logical OR operators always return the first "truthy" value.

```
'foo' || 'bar' = 'foo'
false || 'bar' = 'bar'
```